# Django - First call to reverse is slow

Tags: django

I have to call several times Django `reverse` method in order to return several urls to the client.
The first `reverse` call takes between 1 and 2 seconds while all the following, even with different routes are very fast.

What exactly is happening with the first one ? 
Is there a way to speed this up ?

Comment: Can you see any DB queries being run on the first call? You may have some queries being executed in your forms/views/urls

Comment: @IainShelvington I can't see any...

Comment: Looks like there's some caching happening on the first reverse call - but "between 1 and 2 seconds" is waaayyy too much indeed. Now why it takes so long is impossible to answer without much more details...

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers Yes I understand. Have you got any tips on how I should investigate ?

Comment: The only thing I can see is that all the time taken by reverse is due to _populate...

Comment: How many urls do you have ??? (I mean: urlpatterns). On my desktop, 1000 calls to reverse take =~ 0.04 seconds for an url with dynamic parts - one single call taking 0.0002s -, and this is on a rather large project, so there's really something fishy here.

Comment: More than two hundreds. After the first call, it is as fast as you.